# Controlling new gitolite repository names

Tags: hook, gitolite

I want to add a hook to my gitolite installation so that if the `conf/gitolite.conf` file is pushed and contains a new repository with a name that does not conform to my naming convention, the push will fail.

Can this be done without hacking the gitolite internals?

I am using gitolite 1.5.4.

Answer (score 3):

On the other hand, if you're talking about not trusting the *admin* to create repo names with the proper naming convention, you have several solutions and alternatives.

(1) is it sufficient to warn him so he can log on to the server, remove the offending repo, and fix up the config again?

If so, use a PRE_CREATE or POST_CREATE trigger (see triggers.html in the gitolite docs).  Check argument 2, test it, and print a noisy message if needed.

(2) if a warning is not sufficient, and you need to kill it outright, use a PRE_CREATE trigger, except it has to be in perl.  Use src/lib/Gitolite/Triggers/AutoCreate.pm as a model, except you have to check $_[1] (the second argument).

(3) are you also an admin, perhaps the "main" one?  If so, see delegation (see deleg.html in the gitolite documentation).  This will have more constraints though (like if he is allowed to add keys, he will simply add a new key with *your* name and thus bypass the restriction.

Answer (score 0):

First, upgrade to the latest Gitolite (1.5.4 is more than two years ago)

Second, the "internal" feature of Gitolite allowing to limit the creation of a repo based on a named is called "wild repos" ("wildcard repos"), or "users created repos"

If is available with [Gitolite V2 or G2](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/progit.html#progit_article_Wildcard_repositories__) (not sure about V1), and [Gitolite V3 or g3](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/wild.html).

> The wildrepos feature allows you to specify access control rules using regular expression patterns, so you can have many actual repos being served by a single set of rules in the config file.
>   The regex pattern can also include the word CREATOR in it, allowing you to parametrise the name of the user creating the repo.